# using nested tee does not produce the good results

Tags: shell, tee

Nested tee is not working as expected, see the differents tests above :

test is a small file (approx. 550 kb) :

```
$ >test
$ for _I in `seq 1 100000`; do
        echo "$_I" >> test
done
$ wc -l test
100000 test
```

Here is some code with nested tee :

```
$ cat test.sh
echo "1 :"
cat "$1" |\
 tee >(paste -sd+ | bc -l)\
     >(wc -l)\
     >(sort -k1 -n\
    tee >(uniq -c | wc -l)\
        >(uniq -c | awk '{ print $1 }' | paste -sd+ | bc -l)\
            >(tail -n 1)\
            >(head -n 1) &>/dev/null) &>/dev/null
sleep 20
echo "2:"
cat "$1" |\
 tee >(paste -sd+ | bc -l)\
     >(wc -l)\
     >(sort -k1 -n | uniq -c\
    tee >(wc -l)\
            >(awk '{ print $1 }' | paste -sd+ | bc -l)\
     >(sort -k1 -n |\
    tee >(tail -n 1)\
            >(head -n 1) &>/dev/null) &>/dev/null) &>/dev/null
sleep 20
echo "3:"
cat "$1" |\
 tee >(paste -sd+ | bc -l)\
     >(wc -l)\
     >(sort -k1 -n | uniq -c | wc -l)\
     >(sort -k1 -n | uniq -c | awk '{ print $1 }' | paste -sd+ | bc -l)\
     >(sort -k1 -n | tail -n 1)\
     >(sort -k1 -n | head -n 1) &>/dev/null
sleep 20
```

That's producing this results :

```
1 :
0
14139
99962730
2:
0
100000
5000050000
3:
1
100000
100000
100000
100000
5000050000
```

Here is some code without any tee redirection :

```
$ cat test2.sh 
echo "4 :"
echo "sum : `cat $1 | paste -sd+ | bc -l`"
echo "count numbers : `cat $1 | wc -l`"
echo "count uniq : `cat $1 | sort -k1 -n| uniq -c | wc -l`"
echo "uniq sort and sum : `cat $1 | sort -k1 -n | uniq -c | awk '{ print $1 }' | paste -sd+ | bc -l`"
echo "max : `cat $1 | sort -k1 -n | tail -n 1`"
echo "min : `cat $1 | sort -k1 -n | head -n 1`"
```

Here are the results for reference :

```
$ ./test2.sh test
4 :
sum : 5000050000
count numbers : 100000
count uniq : 100000
uniq sort and sum : 100000
max : 100000
min : 1
```

Can someone explain me why cases 1 and 2 in test.sh doesn't work as expected ?

Comment: You mentioned you have something you tried before. Could you go ahead and post it so everyone can see what you have tried?

Comment: @Erik : here it is :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok:

- you are missing `|` on line 5 and line 15. You probably didn't mean to execute
  `sort -k1 -n tee <(...) <(...) ...` but `sort -k1 -n | tee <(...) <(...) ...`
- `head` utility exits after reading the first line. After it exists, it closes the pipe, which makes tee exit "prematurely". Consider the following:

```
$ seq 10000 | tee >(head -n1) >(tail -n1) >/dev/null
1
10000    # fine
$ seq 100000 | tee >(head -n1) >(tail -n1) >/dev/null
1
14139  # erroro, this is not ok. tail should have outputted 100000 here. Why doesn't it?
$ seq 100000 | tee >(sponge | head -n1 ) >(tail -n1) >/dev/null
100000   # sponge fixes it
1
$ seq 100000 | tee --output-error=warn >(head -n1) >(tail -n1) >/dev/nul
1
tee: /dev/fd/63: Broken pipe  # head exists which closes pipe and that makes tee exit here
10000000
# seq 10000000 | tee -p >(head -n1) >(tail -n1) >/dev/null
1
10000000  # works as expected
```

The default for `tee` is to exit on error when writing to any of the pipes. Option `-p` makes `tee` ignore errors when writing to pipes and go on after any of the pipes exit.

The following is case 1 fixed with output (different indentation, but it's the same):

```
cat "$1" | tee -p >/dev/null \
    >(paste -sd+ | bc -l) \
    >(wc -l) \
    >(sort -k1 -n | tee -p >/dev/null \
            >(uniq -c | wc -l) \
            >(uniq -c | awk '{ print $1 }' | paste -sd+ | bc -l) \
            >(tail -n 1) \
            >(head -n1) \
    )
```

```
1
100000
100000
100000
100000
5000050000
```

This is case 2 fixed:

```
cat "$1" | tee -p >/dev/null \
        >(paste -sd+ | bc -l) \
        >(wc -l) \
        >(sort -k1 -n | uniq -c | tee -p >/dev/null \
                >(wc -l) \
                >(awk '{ print $1 }' | paste -sd+ | bc -l) \
                >(sort -k1 -n | tee -p >/dev/null \
                        >(tail -n 1) \
                        >(head -n1)
                )
        )
```

```
      1 1
      1 99999
100000
100000
100000
5000050000
```

I guess this one will be the "fastest" (ie. only one `uniq -c` call compared to case 1) and I guess this is probably what you meant for case 2:

```
cat "$1" | tee >/dev/null \
        >(paste -sd+ | bc -l) \
        >(wc -l) \
        >(sort -k1 -n | tee -p >/dev/null \
                >(uniq -c | tee -p >/dev/null \
                        >(wc -l) \
                        >(awk '{ print $1 }' | paste -sd+ | bc -l) \
                ) \
                >(tail -n 1) \
                >(head -n1)
        )
```

And it outputs the same as case 1.

As a side note, the output from these process substitutions and `tee` command is not synchronized. I mean that the order of the output is actually random and it is pure luck that the line `5000050000` gets on the last line.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, that's perfect :-)
I missed the -p option of tee, because I did not make the link with the man page : "diagnose errors writing to non pipes" is obviously clear but does not seem to be linked with "prematuraly" closing pipes from head from example.
Good point using sponge to hilight the explanation !